# Encoding an array with UTF8 strings before json_encode trouble

Tags: php, utf-8

I'm trying to process an array of tweets using `array_walk` encode the text into UTF8 so that any chinese characters are handled properly.

```
array_walk($tweet_data, function(&$tweet, $key) {
    $tweet['text'] = iconv('Windows-1250', 'UTF-8', $tweet['text']);
});
```

When I do this, I get the error "Detected an illegal character in input string"

I've also tried this using `utf8_encode`.

```
array_walk($tweet_data, function(&$tweet, $key) {
        $tweet['text'] = utf8_encode($tweet['text']);
    });
```

And this passes through without any issue, but when the text is then displayed on the page, the characters are all wrong.

How can I properly handle UTF8 characters before passing into json_encode so it doesn't break?

Comment: `json_encode($array, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE) `

Comment: Unforunately, that doesn't help. I've tried that already and json_encode just returns an empty result.

Answer (score 3):

This simple php function converts recursively all values of an array to UTF8.
The function mb_detect_encoding (line 4) checks if the value already is in UTF8, this way it will not reconvert.

```
function utf8_converter($array)
{
    array_walk_recursive($array, function(&$item, $key){
        if(!mb_detect_encoding($item, 'utf-8', true)){
                $item = utf8_encode($item);
        }
    });

    return $array;
}
```

Comment: This is almost exactly what I'm doing with the array_walk. I've added in the if statement, and it looks like my strings are already utf8 anyway, so this just garbles it.

Answer (score 1):

[Windows-1250](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1250) cannot encode Chinese:

> Windows-1250 is a code page used under Microsoft Windows to represent
>   texts in Central European and Eastern European languages that use
>   Latin script, such as Polish, Czech, Slovak, Hungarian, Slovene,
>   Bosnian, Croatian, Serbian (Latin script), Romanian (before 1993
>   spelling reform) and Albanian. It may also be used with the German
>   language

Neither can [ISO-8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1):

> is generally intended for Western European languages (see below for a
>   list).

I think you are trying to convert from A to B and you don't know what A is. If you're fully sure is isn't UTF-8 already, you should at least try an encoding that's specifically [designed to hold that lang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_character_encoding).

Comment: I've done `mb_detect_encoding` on the strings and they're already in UTF-8 before passing to json_encode, like they should be.